# Javascript: Load different stylesheet for IE9

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-9, stylesheet, browser-detection

So I was looking to write a function that would test if user is using IE / IE9 and conditionally load a separate stylesheet if true. Have read through a ton of documentation but there doesn't seem to be a single aggregated consistent and recent (circa 2011) answer that I could find.

So the questions are:

1) What is your preferred and most modern browser detection method? Checking for `document.attachEvent` is what I use but is there a better way?

2) What is your preferred way of conditionally changing stylesheets dynamically based on browser? `setAttribute` doesn't work on `<style>`, not sure how to do this.

Thanks in advance,
Denis

Comment: just curious, why would you load a separate style for IE?

Comment: If it's to fix issues with IE, you should first get your core CSS looking as good as possible across all browsers, because if your site looks absolutely terrible in IE8/9 then there are probably just errors in your HTML/CSS. Then beyond that, to fix things that IE legitimately does have a problem with, conditional comments wrapped around a CSS link in your HTML is a much simpler solution than bringing JS in to play, so I would suggest looking into that.

Comment: _"What is your preferred way of conditionally changing stylesheets dynamically based on browser?"_ - I prefer not to do it at all. If you _must_ distinguish between browsers IE is almost always the problem child but fortunately it processes conditional comments so use them...

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for [Conditional Comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
your IE9 stylesheet
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by many methods

**1) CSS check**

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>your stylesheet for ie < 7 <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>your stylesheet for ie7<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>your stylesheet for ie8<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>your stylesheet for ie9<![endif]-->
```

**2) by javascript check**

```
var isIe = (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer")
var isIe9 = (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer" && parseInt(navigator.appVersion) == 4 && navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 9") != -1)
```

**3) using third party libray like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/)**

Comment: This is not valid JS `var isIe9 = var isIe55 =` and why test the appName twice? And why load Facebook namespace when the question is about CSS?

Comment: here is only the answer how to check for IE/IE9 not to do solve the full problem

Comment: But the question was _test if user is using IE / IE9 and conditionally load a separate stylesheet if true_

Comment: then is the answer wrong ? questioner don't have any programming skills to replace facebook script with his stylesheet?

Comment: not wrong, just confusing. It is better now and you fixed your syntax error. I would still just use `var isIe = (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer");
var isIe9 = (isIe && navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 9") != -1)`